# How to call JavaScript inside a WebBrowser control?

Tags: javascript, c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I want to call the JavaScript function "Goto" like this:

```
javascript:Goto('DM_NEW_OBJECT.ASPX?DM_CAT_ID=2063&amp;DM_PARENT_ID=2217&amp;INPUTSELECTION=&amp;DM_OBJECT_ID=0&amp;PACK_ID=0&amp;CASE_ID=0&amp;mode=0&amp;SITE=Default');
```

the function is located in the `DefaultGeneral.aspx` page, and I need to call it from within a WebBrowser control:

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("http://mySite/DefaultGeneral.aspx");
```

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since you are using a WebBrowser object, I will assume that this is actually a Windows forms question and not an asp.net question.

You should look at the [InvokeScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc491132(v=vs.110).aspx) function of the web browser.

Let's say your webpage has the following function:

**WITHOUT PARAMETERS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Function Without Parameters
    function JavaScriptFunctionWithoutParameters() {
        outputID.innerHTML = "JavaScript function called!";
    }
</script>
```

You would want to call it the following way:

```
this.webBrowser.InvokeScript("JavaScriptFunctionWithoutParameters");
```

**WITH PARAMETERS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Function With Parameters
    function Goto(someParameter) {
        outputID.innerHTML = someParameter;
    }
</script>
```

You would call it like this:

```
object[] param = new object[1];
param [0] = "DM_NEW_OBJECT.ASPX?DM_CAT_ID=2063&amp;DM_PARENT_ID=2217&amp;INPUTSELECTION=&amp;DM_OBJECT_ID=0&amp;PACK_ID=0&amp;CASE_ID=0&amp;mode=0&amp;SITE=Default";
this.webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("Goto", param );
```

Answer (score 1):

In C# you have to do something like this:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"CallMyFunction","MyFunction()",true);
```

Or this:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(),"hwa","alert('Hello World');",true);
```

Check out this doc...

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.clientscript(v=vs.110).aspx
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe ... put the javascript:Goto into the

`<body onload="">`

... inside the quotes.