# How do i get contentWindow in C# webbrowser?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, webbrowser-control

```
wb.Document.GetElementById("RandomIframe").Children[1].contentWindow.document.children[0].children[1].children[11].children[7].children[0].children[1].click();
```

Error message

'`HtmlElement`' does not contain a definition for '`contentWindow`' and no extension method '`contentWindow`' accepting a first argument of type '`HtmlElement`' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Hello, please read [MCVE] before asking question

Comment: What the world?

Comment: use `dynamic`. c# != javascript

Comment: No offense but just that one line of code screams you need to rethink your whole strategy.  There's no reason for all that specific tunneling.  If you absolutely have to do that then you have to paste the entire web view for us to see it as well; and even then; I doubt anyone will want to dig into that nesting.  I get what you're trying to do but there should never be a reason to write code this way.

Answer (score 0):

here is js code that could work:

```

function invokeClick(){
document.GetElementById("RandomIframe").contentWindow.document.GetElementById("yourclickabledom").click();
}

```
place js code to you web page, or implement a c# string to wrap those code, then inject code to your html by this post:
[How to inject Javascript in WebBrowser control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153748/how-to-inject-javascript-in-webbrowser-control)

then follow this post to invoke it:
[How to call javascript inside a WebBrowser control in winforms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27252703/how-to-call-javascript-inside-a-webbrowser-control-in-winforms)

make sure your html page is completely loaded with webbrowser event: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted(v=vs.110).aspx